# codeception error after inserting laravel5 module

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, codeception

i have installed codeception globally. it works fine when i run `codecept run functional` command. when i insert laravel5 module into `functional.suite.yml` as per instruction from codeception website documentation, it gives me error like this.
[image]

when i remove laravel5 module `codecept run` works normally. anyone knows how to tackle that error? should i install codeception locally instead of globally?

**Note :** i don't use homestead/vagrant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error doesn't seem to be related to Laravel5 module.

Your problem is that you have 2 conflicting versions of PHPUnit installed.

You have PHPUnit 5.2.12 installed in vendor directory,
but your global Codeception install is bundled with PHPUnit 4.8.23.

There are 2 ways to solve it:
a) uninstall PHPUnit from your project.
b) install Codeception with Composer.

Comment: Or i injecting codecept.phar to my project directory and it's works somehow.