# Codeception 1.6 - class CodeGuy not found error

Tags: codeception

I've installed Codeception and set up for a specific symfony bundle with the command:

```
vendor/bin/codecept bootstrap src/Elmo/RecruitmentBundle --namespace RecruitmentBundle
```

The required functional, unit and acceptance subdirs have been created for that bundle along with a `codeception.yml` file.

I am able to generate a unit test using the command:

```
vendor/bin/codecept generate:test unit MyThing\\MyTask -c src/Elmo/RecruitmentBundle
```

But when i go to run this test with:

```
vendor/bin/codecept run -c src/Elmo/RecruitmentBundle unit
```

I get the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CodeGuy' not found in /var/www/html/pms/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/TestCase/Test.php on line 39
```

Reference to CodeGuy class in MyTaskTest is:

```
@var \RecruitmentBundle\CodeGuy
```

and reference in unit.suite.yml is:

```
class_name: CodeGuy
```

I guessing this is an issue related to the path to CodeGuy created in the bundle versus the path specified in `unit.suite.yml` . I've tried changing the path to e.g. `\RecruitmentBundle\CodeGuy` in `unit.suite.yml` but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What version of Codeception are you using?

Comment: codeception version is  1.8

Comment: It's an ancient version. But I have looked at the code and that error can't possibly happen in any release of 1.8, it looks like you are running 1.6 there.

Comment: Hi @Naktibalda you are correct, version is 1.6.4.1. Would this issue be resolved by upgrading to a newer version? This version was compatible with my current version of symfony, and more importantly, php unit

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't help. The oldest version I've ever used was 2.0.13

Comment: Hi @Naktibalda, i got around this problem by installing codeception.phar instead of using composer. this way was able to use the latest version of codeception

Answer (score 0):

Followed instructions for installing codeception phar file here: [Codeception Installation](http://codeception.com/install)

This enabled me to use the latest version of codeception, and avoid any issues which were encountered when installing via composer, such as dependency conflicts and the class not found error

Comment: If your project has any shared dependencies with Codeception: https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/2.2/composer.json
using phar file often causes unexpected errors in the code, because of different versions of libraries installed by composer and present in phar file.

Comment: https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/3167
https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/3082
https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/2534
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36150127/how-to-configure-codeception-for-functional-test-with-symfony2/36151983#36151983
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36015950/codeception-error-after-inserting-laravel5-module/36017333

Comment: Hi @Naktibalda you are correct, i discovered this issue when pointing to Symfony and Doctrine modules in my app directory from acceptance suite.suite.yml file, uses the existing(older) version of PHP unit and throws an error on a function which doesnt exist in the older version